# Different types of ICMP

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis, icmp, tcpdump

I have a task on which I have spent a lot of time. I am not fluent in Linux, but I can manage basic things.

The task is to gather different types of ICMP packets. I can harvest them by `tcpdump` (which I prefer) or Wireshark.

I am able get the ICMP types of `echo reply` and `echo request` using `ping`, and `time exceeded` using `tracepath` or `traceroute`. Now, what I am trying to get is `unreachable` or `timestamp` or something else. I need two more types, however I don't know a way to produce.

I have tried pinging a nonexistent host or wrong port, and using `tracepath` the same way, but I am not getting anything.

Can someone advise me or tell me what commands I can use, and in which way, to obtain two more types of ICMP packets?

edit (answer to comment):
I guess there are no matter which ones. I must to catch some types and describe them. May be from the same category as reply, request and time exceeded, but should be different ones.

Comment: Some ICMP messages are generated by hosts, and some are generated by routers. Which are you looking for? As far as Linux commands, you should ask on one of the Linux forums for those.

Comment: This question comes across sounding suspiciously like a homework question, which is off topic here. If it is not school work, please [edit] your question to provide more context about why you are asking and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I will recommend you use a Python module Scapy to generate those packets.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the point of this task was for you to figure out how to generate and capture different types of ICMP messages. Without directly giving you the answers, I will point you in the direction of how to figure it out.

[RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792) describes ICMP messages. There are different possible sources for ICMP messages:

> Code
>
> 0 = net unreachable;
>
> 1 = host unreachable;
>
> 2 = protocol unreachable;
>
> 3 = port unreachable;
>
> 4 = fragmentation needed and DF set;
>
> 5 = source route failed.
>
> Codes 0, 1, 4, and 5 may be received from a gateway.  Codes 2 and
> 3 may be received from a host.

You say want `unreachable` messages. Code 0 seems to be a good target, and it comes from a gateway (router), How do you suppose you can get a router to generate one of those codes? Remember that this is something that a router must be able to know.

This is the sort of thing which you should be looking for when figuring out how to generate and capture the messages.

The RFCs are good sources to understand the protocol, and once you understand the protocol (apparently the point of this exercise), it becomes easier to figure out how to use it.